# How to stop the custom view refreshing?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I have created a custom view using onDraw(Canvas canvas) method in a class which extends View class.I am using invalidate() method to refresh my view in every 2 second.But now I want to stop refreshing the view after some time say after 120 seconds.How will I stop invalidate() method. Any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

**Here's my code**:-

```
public GameView(Context context){ 
super(context);

Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(
             Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
}

@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int imageWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = bmp.getHeight();

        int width = display.getWidth();
        System.out.println("Width = " +width);
        int height = display.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Height = " +height);
        Random randomX,randomY;
        randomX = new Random();
        randomY = new Random();

        x = randomX.nextInt(width - imageWidth);
        System.out.println("X = " +x);
        y = randomY.nextInt(height - imageHeight);
        System.out.println("Y = " +y);

        Rect dst = new Rect(x , y , x + imageWidth , y + imageHeight);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null , dst , null);
        System.out.println("dst = " +dst);
        try{
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        invalidate();

    }
```

Comment: From where do you call invalidate()?

Comment: could you post some sample code?

Comment: Please see the edited content.

Comment: I don't believe that nobody has answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a counter (e.g. int myCounter) and increase its value by 2 in each cycle. You can then enclose your code that calls the thread and the invalidate() inside a check instruction in order for you to execute this program block only if you variable myCounter is less than 120.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't personally block the UI thread by calling Thread.sleep(1000) within my draw method. Instead, I would use a Handler object, then I'd call recursive postDelayed calls in order to schedule repeated invalidate() calls. Finally, I'd code 2 special functions to start the "animation" and to interrupt it if needed (following code is NOT tested... Just a snippet I wrote in a few sec to illustrate my point. Caveat emptor.). Note that what which was described by Aderito Brinca is accurate as well, although it doesn't solve the UI thread blocking issue as mentioned above.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private boolean isAnimStarted=false;
final private long refreshIntervalMsec = 2000;     //2 seconds refresh rate
final private long maxRefreshTimeMsec = 120000; //120 seconds deadline
private long systemTimeMillisOnStart = -1L;
private Display display = null; //within a local variable declared in GameView
//constructor this variable was useless. Now that it is a private
//class member, it can be used by overridden onDraw or Draw methods.

public GameView(Context context){ 
    super(context);
    display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(
             Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    //INSERT THE REST OF YOUR CONSTRUCTOR CODE HERE
}

public boolean isGameViewAnimStarted(){ //CALL this in order to check for running anim
    return isAnimStarted;
}

public void startGameViewAnim(){ //CALL this to start your anim thing
    isAnimStarted=true;
    systemTimeMillisOnStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    refreshAnim();
}

private void refreshAnim(){
    invalidate();
    if(  (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - systemTimeMillisOnStart) < maxRefreshTimeMsec){
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){              
                refreshAnim();
            }
        }, refreshIntervalMsec);
    }
    else{
        stopGameViewAnim();
    }
}

public void stopGameViewAnim(){ //CALL this to interrupt your anim thing
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    isAnimStarted=false;
}



@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas);
    //INSERT YOUR CODE HERE

}
```